# Using FFMpeg Video Frames From directories

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ffmpeg, sh

I have hundreds of folders containing video, audio, images.. which I need to create video thumbs foreach 10 seconds of video of every video file found (mp4/avi/mov/3gp) and placed in one location /thumbs/.

I have this, which I've been trying to figure out for days.

```
find . -exec ffmpeg -i {} -vf fps=1/8 {}.png \;
```

or

```
find /Users/media/Desktop/videoframes/input/  -regex ".*\.\(mp4\)" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file;  do  ffmpeg -i $file -vf fps=1/8 ${file}%d.png done
```

I know little about the syntax but want to learn more but Im stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for ffmpeg syntax or shell syntax to run ffmpeg on the folders?

Comment: divide and conquer!. Get one of your find cmds to work so it will display a very clean list of all the files you intend to process. `-regex` seems like overkill as `-name '*.mp4'` should find all mp4 files. I like that you're using `print0`. So try `find ... -print0 | xargs -o /bin/ls -l` first to see that you're getting a perfectly clean list of files. Then take 1 file, and mess with `ffmpeg` options until the one file is working. Then  you can replace `ls -l` with `ffmpeg ...` . If your "new" command doesn't work, then post a new Q and include 1-2 filenames that aren't working as expected.

Comment: I twitted this and it works exactly how I want it but two things. I cant seem to make the regex work, and Id love if the outputted images were put in one folder. 
  find . -regex ".*\.\(mp4\)"  -exec ffmpeg -i {} -vf fps=1/8 {}Frame55Grab%d.png  \;<code>